# Single sign on @username giving anonymous with Xpages

Tags: xpages

I think that I have configured web SSO (SPNEGO) on our test 8.5.3 server.  I created a test discussion data base and when I access it with a web client my credentials are displayed.  But if I acces my Xpage first the @Username function shows Anonymous.  If I display the discussion page first then return to my Xpage the @Username gives the correct name.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check the ACL of the databases and see what anonymous is set to.

I suspect that in the discussion anonymous is set to 'no access' so it triggers the login process via SPNEGO and logs you in with your credentials but the XPage app may have anonymous set as reader so it is just letting you in as anonymous.

When you access the discussion before the xpage app the ltpatoken SSO cookie is being set so when you hit the xpage app it knows your logged in via SSO which is why it is showing the correct credentials in that case.

Comment: Thanks Declan that was it.  Do you know if it is possible to have both anonymous and SSO ?